# how to change a single letter in filenames all over the file system?

Tags: linux, file-io, command-line, filesystems

i have hundreds of files with special characters ('æ', 'ø' and 'å') in their filenames.

i cannot copy these to my external mntfs disk without renaming.

the files are in dozens of different folders. there are thousands of other files without these letters in there as well.

i'd like to replace the special characters with their placeholders ('ae', 'oe' and 'aa'), while keeping the rest of the filename intact.

i'm on ubuntu. i'm thinking of using grep, sed and tr, but i don't know exactly how.

Comment: The `find` utility will probably serve quite useful here. You could recursively find all files in `root` that contain a special character, then apply substitution rules accordingly.

Comment: I'd like to point out that the characters aren't "special". They're quite common, especially in danish. They're just not encodable in ASCII.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rename` command from util-linux package.
For example,

```
find / -type f -exec rename 'â' 'a' {} \;
```

Comment: rename wasn't able to handle the special characters.

Comment: that's because this isn't how tho use `rename`. it should read: `find / -type f -exec rename 's/ä/ae/' {} \;`

Comment: Different distributions have different `rename`s. Some use `rename` from `util-linux`, and others (Debian-based i think), use the Perl-based `rename`.

Comment: ubuntu is debian-based and uses perl-based rename per default

Answer (score 0):

[convmv](http://www.j3e.de/linux/convmv/man/) is used to convert filenames between encodings. I'm sure it can solve your problem, even if it might not be *exactly* what you asked for.